# Running mocha tests from node

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs, mocha.js, istanbul

I am trying to run my mocha tests from node . The ultimate goal is to add code-coverage via istanbul/blanket and generate a lcov file for input into sonar for code coverage.

This is a sample project on which I am trying 
https://github.com/rajarshigoswami/Todos

The mocha tests are under 
https://github.com/rajarshigoswami/Todos/tree/master/test/mocha

The tests are running from browser, but when I am trying via node, it wont pick up any of the spec files.

How to use :
run : npm install
then : grunt

My questions are :

1. What am I missing or doing wrong here?
2. How do I integrate blanket.js/istanbul to generate lcov files

Answer (score 6):

I would change a few things. Simply add this to `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "test":
  "./node_modules/.bin/istanbul test ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- -R spec"
}
```

Now, when you do `npm test` it runs mocha and istambul

This [article](http://www.jayway.com/2014/03/28/running-scripts-with-npm/)  will help you

Comment: Yes, using npm is a great option too. Still it's just using mocha directly without any test or task runner.

Comment: the truth is that since I discovered the power of npm scripts, use it for everything

Comment: This will work if I didn't use requirejs. All my external dependencies are loaded via require, so the tests fail

Answer (score 2):

There's a few options depending what you need to do:

1) So firstly it would be good to know what you actually mean by running tests in node? For example I use to `mocha` to test server-side code for my `node.js` applications. It just runs the tests without relying on any specific environment (except `node.js` obviously). Without any other tools simply run `mocha your/custom/test/directory/` (that assume your `mocha` is installed globally).
So as long as your view test don't rely on being run in a Web Browser you're good.

2) If what you just want run your front-end tests without need of opening SpecRunner.html manually in a web browser, I highly recommend using `karma` test runner, with a headless browser like `PhantomJS`.

3) Finally if you already have the `grunt` installed just grab the `mocha-istanbul` npm module. The configuration is really simple:

```
mocha_istanbul: {
    coverage: {
        // where your tests leave
        src: 'server/tests',
        options: {
            // instrument only spec files
            mask: '*.spec.js',
            // output a human readable website
            // (along site regular test summary produced by mocha)
            reportFormats: ['html']
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see there are some options out there. Just grab the one that suits your project the best.

Comment: This works if the dependencies are declared in every file, which is a pain. I have a main.js where all the require dependencies are loaded. While testing from browser, i load that first, which in turn calls each of the specs, where the same dependencies are just used as define

Comment: That's why I use Karma to load all the dependencies :) it works really well.

Comment: Any chance you have any sample repo. The one given here doesnt work 
https://github.com/kjbekkelund/karma-requirejs

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are trying to test code that using `requirejs`

in order for the you mocha spec to work with `phantom` and `requirejs` on a grunt task runner you can use [`grunt-mocha-phantomjs`](https://github.com/jdcataldo/grunt-mocha-phantomjs)

for you other issue of using `istambol` check [this link](https://gist.github.com/fhemberger/7234766) (this link is more suitable for your purpose because its use backbone also (-: )

Comment: I had tried that also. the problem is if i place a console.log inside my tests, it runs. That means the tests are running, but mocha doesnt know that. 

Also if I run via phantom.js, mocha complains that run() isn't called, but ideally you dont need it for running via node

Comment: did you try [this](https://github.com/accordionpeas/grunt-mocha-require-phantom#test-file-path-name) `window.mochaPhantomJS`?